# как установить приложение на телефон

Tags: android

Есть телефон с операционной системой android 4.2.2 и есть файл apk. При попытке установить этот файл в качестве приложения появляется ошибка  - Недостаточно памяти освободите место. Свободной памяти в телефоне 1.53 ГБ. Как его установить?

Comment: возможно, приложению действительно нужно сколько памяти. Вариант два - память есть, но она на sdcard, а нужна в основной памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim, приложение около 3мб, sdcard нету, только память телефона

Comment: размер apk это не размер того, сколько приложение хочет. Хотя может это само приложение при установке такое выдает:)

Comment: @KoVadim кстати да, еще очень важно - приложение для диагностики автомобиля

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app

Comment: @user504345 - я думаю, что нужно хотя бы писать, сколько именно памяти свободно. Имя приложения, которое устанавливаете, почему не с playmarket. Тут не очень любят "угадайку со щипцами"

Comment: @KoVadim приложение для диагностики автомобиля fap, памяти в телефоне 2,1 гб, свободно 1,5гб. Приложение без проблем запускается на других устройствах. Цель установить приложение на конкретный телефон alcatel 5036d

Comment: запускается ли оно на аналогичном устройстве? Но похоже это не для этого сайта вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim, аналогичного устройства к сожалению нету

Comment: возможно, это особенность этой версии прошивки или устройства. Возможно, приложение собрано с более свежим сдк

Comment: @KoVadim вспомнил еще один момент. На этом же устройстве стояла более совершенная версия этого приложения 1.62, но она по какой то причине не подключалась к автомобилю. Пришлось ее удалить, что бы установить версию 1.5

Comment: Свободное место на накопителе аппарата не означает что оно доступно для приложений. Не помню как сейчас, но на 4.2.2 точно под приложения выделялся отдельный раздел, у меня было 500Мб при общем объёме накопителя 4Гб. Часть этой памяти ещё и резервировалась - приложения устанавливались только при наличии свободных 100Мб + объём под установку + размер APK

Comment: @woesss как посмотреть этот раздел, и сколько в нем места?

Comment: Без понятия, в разных прошивках по-разному. Где-то в настройках в списке приложений либо в разделе память/хранилище может отображаться количество занятой/свободной. Если там есть свежий Google Play - можно в нём посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

У меня была подобная проблема на Андроид 4.1 (SDK 16). Кратко: из-за несовершенства ОС ранних версий при интенсивной установке/удаления программ накапливалась лишняя информация мешающая нормальному функционированию устройства.

Опираясь на ответы [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-to-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error-on-android/10042289#10042289) сразу получилось просто переделать манифест и устанавливать программы на внешнюю SD карточку.
Затем я удалил множество файлов с папки Data через Android Studio - Device Explorer и место освободилось, программы устанавливаются до сих пор нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил, опишу что делал - через поиск root проводника нашел все файлы с именем приложения которое устанавливал и удалил их. после этого все заработало